# PHP recognizing a full stop before a word

Tags: php, regex, text

I have a method that looks for the word 'not' and then a word after it but if i have a sentence such as:

> this is good. Not good

for some reason the 'not' will not be picked up due to the full stop that is in front of it, anyone know how to get around this, the code is below

```
   preg_match_all("/(?<=\b not\b)\b good\b/i", $find, $matches);
```

Comment: list of positive words in a database

Comment: and we need to guess it? Please replace `$poswords` in your regular expression with the actual value that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @zerkms: Changing it to "that" shows the problem clearly..

Comment: @Truth: I wouldn't wonder if it is `foo,bar,baz` as a comma separated *list* there. And I'd better wait another couple of minutes rather than guessing and wasting time for unreal case ;-)

Comment: why not try stristr? or other word compare functions.

Comment: $poswords is not the problem...the problem is when 'not' appears after a full stop

Comment: @linda: it is not how it works. If it is not a problem - just remove it from the regex, so the example become small and possible to reproduce for us, without requirement to make any *assumptions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` matches a word boundary, which is the position between two characters where one is a word character and one is not. Word characters are `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. You are matching a word boundary before a space before the `not`, and there isn't a word boundary there because the string has a full-stop as the previous character.

That is, there isn't  word boundary between a full-stop and  space, because *neither* is a word character.

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: does mean theres no way around it ?

Comment: It simply means you have to look for exactly what you want to find. If you want to isolate `not` as a word, use `\bnot\b` with no spaces in that expression. That will match `not` with a non-word character before `n` and after `t`. That could be a fullstop, space, hash sign...